# how to use default constructor while using composition

Tags: c++, oop

Here is the code where i used composition. I removed the non-relevant functions to make it little easier to understand .When i run this code using parametrized constructor, it work fine. But if i use default constructor while initilizing it does not work, the code terminate in between.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class link
{
    const char* name;
public:
    link() :name("null")
    {};
    link(const char n[]) :name(n)
    {};
    ~link()
    {

        cout << "destructor called " << endl;
    };
};
class webpage
{
private:
    double height;
    double width;
    link* links;
public:
    webpage() :height(10), width(10),links(new link[1])
    {};
    webpage(double hw, link* hyperlinks) :height(hw), width(hw), links(hyperlinks)
    {   };
    webpage(double h, double w, link* hyperlinks) :height(h), width(w), links(hyperlinks)
    {   };
    ~webpage()
    {
            delete [] links;
        cout << "page destructor called " << endl;
    };
    void showdata(int linkno)
    {
        cout << "height: " << height << endl;
        cout << "width: " << width << endl;
        cout << "links " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < linkno; i++)
        {
            cout << "link #" << i + 1 << " = " << links[i].getname() << endl;
        }

    }
};
class website
{
private:
    const char* name;
    webpage* wpgs;
public:
    website() :name("null"),wpgs(new webpage[1])
    {};
    website(const char n[], webpage* page) :name(n), wpgs(page)
    {};
    ~website()
    {
        delete[] wpgs;
        cout << "website destructor " << endl;
    };
    void showdata(int linkno, int pageno)
    {
        cout << "Website name: " << name << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < pageno; j++)
        {
            cout << "Webpage #" << j + 1 << " : " << endl;
            wpgs[j].showdata(linkno);
        }
    }
};
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    link* link1=new link[2] {{"maha"},{"saira"}};
    link* link2=new link[3] {{"areeb"},{"aima"},{"umair"}};
    link* link3=new link[2] {{"ahmad"},{"azra"}};
    link* link4=new link[4] {{"usama"},{"tyabba"},{"ali"},{"hamza"}};
    webpage* page=new webpage[4] {{2,link1},{3.2,5.2,link2},{4,1,link3},{42,13,link4}};
    website site("my website",page);
site.showdata(2,4);

}
```

the above code work fine but if i use default constructor like in below code

```
int main()
{
   link* links;
   webpage* page; 
   website site("website", page);
   site.showdata(1, 1);
}
```

now it won't work. the code with terminate after a bit.
and generate error
error1  'links': unreferenced local variable
error2   uninitialized local variable 'page' used

How can I inlitialize using default constructor
please help.
All the conditions implemented in question are demand of problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using **any** constructor because `links` and `page` are pointers. Pointers do not have constructors.

Maybe you want this?

```
webpage page;
website site("website", &page);
```

Now because `page` is not a pointer the `webpage` default constructor will be called.

Or looking at the rest of your code, probably this is correct.

```
webpage* page = new webpage[1];
website site("website", page);
```

`new webpage[1]` calls the webpage default constructor.